# Quelques questions sur « laconique »

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, grec

1. Y a-t-il un verbe qui correspond au mot *laconique* ?
2. Laconique est-il courant ou est-ce mieux d'utiliser *concis* ?
3. Parmi les différents antonymes visibles [ici](http://www.antonyme.org/antonyme/laconique), lequel est le plus approprié (contexte formel) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 il semble que non (sous réserve).

le contraire a en revanche beaucoup de synonymes: pérorer, palabrer, discourir, disserter, jacasser, ...

2 Comme synonyme, plutôt préférer lapidaire :
*laconique* a une connotation *ennuyeuse*.

3 loquace, les autres sont plus exagérés.

voir le [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laconique).

Comment: Merci vivement. Laconique a toujours une connotation ennuyeuse en français ? On (les grecs) l'utilise pour exprimer parles sans fioritures. Ce  faisant, ce n'est pas toujours enuyeux :-)! Livio et Littré ne donnent pas ce sens.

Comment: sans âme, typiquement déclaration ou style administratif.

Comment: @dimitris Être concis est une qualité (on est précis et ne gaspille pas le temps de son auditeur), être laconique ou lapidaire est un défaut (on ne se donne pas la peine de fournir des détails).

Comment: @jlliagre Je suis bien embêté. Je n'avais jamais interprété *a priori* que laconique ou lapidaire ait été négatifs. Bien sûr, quand le contexte s'y prête, on perçoit qu'il y a une volonté de ne pas assez en dire, mais pas forcément. Aucune trace particulière de volonté de cacher quoi que ce soit, non plus, [au TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/laconique), où de nombreux exemples sont clairement positifs (celui avec *Revenez!*, entre autres, est particulièrement frappant, où le laconisme est contrasté avec la longueur sèche de la lettre dont ce simple mot est le post-scriptum).

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Si *concis* ne vous semble pas pile-poil (il me semble correct, mais ce n'est pas ici mon propos...), que pensez-vous de *succinct* comme synonyme? Il me semble plus courant que *lapidaire*, et peut-être plus à même que *concis* d’être employé avec une connotion négative, si besoin est.

Comment: @Feelew J'ai aussi remarqué ça en regardant le TLFi. Il me semble que les adjectifs laconique et lapidaire sont plus souvent utilisés avec une composante péjorative aujourd'hui, mais je peux me tromper. Si quelqu'un me fait une réponse lapidaire, j'ai l'impression qu'elle me la lancée dessus comme un caillou... En revanche, *concis* me paraît toujours positif, plus que *succinct* qui est plus neutre pour moi.

Comment: Au sujet de (3), loquace est un trait de caractère qui décrit une personne parlant beaucoup -- dans les contextes ayant trait à l'écrit, par exemple "un communiqué laconique", "long" ou "développé" peuvent être des antonymes préférables

Comment: je ne dirais pas de "connotation ennuyeuse". En effet c'est tellement court qu'on n'a pas le temps de s'ennuyer. En revanche j'y verrais un côté "austère". Ce ne me semble pas péjoratif, mais plutôt neutre, pouvant être perçu tantôt comme positif (sang froid et concision) tantôt comme négatif (coté froid et inhumain, voire méprisant)

Answer (score -2):

1- Non
2 - Courant pour dénoncer un discours chiant. "Le discours de tel politique était laconique"...

Comment: 1 La formulation est un peu trop laconique pour constituer une réponse. 2 Quel rapport entre laconique (bref) et chiant ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Qu'est-ce qu'il faut de plus pour la réponse à la question 1 ? Pas besoin d'y aller par quatre chemins. On peut broder : "Madame, Monsieur, Après une étude approfondie du dictionnaire, et en me fondant sur ma grande expérience de la langue française, j'ai pu déterminer avec certitude la réponse à votre question, qui se trouve être la suivante : il n'existe pas, à ma connaissance, de verbe qui correspond au mot laconique. En vous priant d'agréer l'expression de mes sentiments distingués, Bien à vous, XXX". En anglais, des mots qui n'apportent aucune info, on appelle ça du "bullshit".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi La réponse a au moins le mérite d'être laconique, en effet. Mais elle est aussi très catégorique. Peut-être qu’en plus des dictionnaires, une courte recherche Google avec «San Antonio laconiqué-je» offirait-elle un peu de compétition à cette affirmation péremptoire. Pour la petite histoire: *Béru contre San-Antonio*, paru en 1967, au chapitre 4: «— Merveilleux ! **laconiqué-je** derechef, car je parle couramment le seizièmarrondissement moderne, et je peux le lire dans le texte.» Pas obligé de remplir avec du vide et des fleurs décoratives pour étoffer.

Comment: Maintenant, j'admets bien que San-Antonio n'est pas forcément la référence linguistique la plus sobre qui soit.

Comment: @Pasunclue La conjugaison du verbe *laconiquer* risque de mener à des phrases phonétiquement périlleuses ;-)